# Advanced Column Rendering for MVCContrib Grid with MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvccontrib-grid

I'm trying to build a custom column for an MVCContrib grid, but an getting tripped up by the Razor syntax.  Here is my code for building a custom column:

```
@{Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>
    {
        column.For("Data").Do(p => {
        <div>@p.Name</div>
        });
    }).Render();
}
```

How do you mark the line containing the div so that Razor will treat the line as HTML?

Answer (score 11):

The following should work:

```
@(Html
    .Grid<SomeViewModel>(Model)
    .Columns(column => {
        column.Custom(@<div>@item.Name</div>).Named("Data");
    })
)
```

Comment: +1 switching `@{Html.Grid....}` to `@(Html.Grid....)` made my grid show up. Razor enclosures are strange =/

Comment: Thanks for this post; I was originally trying to create my own renderer, but to no avail.  I ended up just using a custom column to display the data how I wanted and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
@(Html.Grid(Model.PaymentFileLogs)
    .AutoGenerateColumns()
    .Columns(extraColumns => extraColumns.For(c => "<i class='icon-warning-sign'></i>").Encode(false))
```